# What effect do unhandled errors have on the .NET CLR?

Tags: .net, memory-management, cpu-usage

I am currently looking for issues causing CPU spikage within one of our applications on one of our servers, and I've noticed tens-of-thousands of unhandled errors messages in the event viewer, within a 3rd party forum software that we use in one of our sites.

What kind of ramifications do unhandled exceptions have on the .NET CLR and would they contribute to an unusually high amount of CPU spikage/usage?   I've also noticed a large amount of memory that does not seem to be GC'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Exception` objects in .NET are, in general, a *fairly heavy* object in that they do take a bit of effort to be instantiated. So lots of those (whether handled or not) could be causing your troubles.

I'd be interested in seeing the frequency, though; tens of thousands over months? weeks? days? shorter?

Comment: An exception is being generated approximately every minute, sometimes 2 or 3 a minute.  Specifically, NullReferenceExceptions

Comment: I'd say if the spiking appears to fit such a pattern of frequency, that could very well be the problem. `Exception`s really should not be getting thrown around that application so frequently; perhaps the error is something that can be addressed?

Comment: Unfortunatly, it would require upgrading the forum software, as we are using compiled assemblies which we do not have access to.  This is why I am digging to see if this is the true cause of the issue or if it is only a minor annoyance.

Comment: Forum threads that have been removed are still being hit by search engines.  When the thread is attempted to be read by the software, it doesn't properly handle the failure -- e.g. check to see if the thread exists before trying to read it from the database.

Comment: Test-Driven Development was invented to prevent such problems, Good luck.

Comment: @George - Ugh; that is horrible. Such an 'error' should be handled in the Forum software by returning a friendly 404 error page, or simply a forum page saying "post deleted" or some such. An exception being generated for such a thing is really bad.

Comment: @George - Something you might consider testing; load some of these links yourself (bad ones) with some extra frequency, and observe the utilization at the same time. That should be able to settle the matter largely.